# Hex Conversion Function to be Python <2.7 Compatible

Tags: python, hex

I've this function to convert on HEX string and delete the 0x section:

```
self.foo = '{:04X}'.format()
```

This works in Python >=2.7 but if i use python 2.6 give me this error:
ValueError: zero length field name in format

How i can fix it to use also in 2.6 python?

Thanks for help

Comment: What do you expect the `.format` method to do here?  You're not passing anything in ...

Comment: does not work in neither python. For python 2.6+ use `'{0:04X}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python2.6 required that you specify a "name" for the field (which explains the `ValueError`'s message).  If you're using positional parameters to `.format`, then the "name" is 0.  e.g. it would look like this:

```
self.foo = '{0:04X}'.format(something)
```

Python2.7 introduced a shortcut so that if the name wasn't specified, it was assumed to be the next positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just good old fashioned `%`?

```
"%04x" % 42
```